# libcurl block until response finishes?

Tags: c, request, libcurl, blocking

How do you block until the request response finished in libcurl? I need to block because `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` [asynchronously writes](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) to the C-String; so I need to be sure that I can get the full output from a request before I act on the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by making the callback function return `return nmemb*size;`

See here for more info: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2002-12/0065.html

```
char *array;
int arraySize = 0;

size_t storeContent(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
  int thisSize = nmemb * size;
  arraySize += thisSize;

  array = realloc(array, arraySize + thisSize);
  strcat(array, ptr);

  return nmemb * size;
}
```